# Differentiate dynamic id

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-blade

How it is possible to differentiate dynamic id with jQuery?

**HTML :**

```
@foreach($listeSeances as $seance)
    ... 

    <div class="modal fade reservationModal" id="reservationModal-{{ $seance->id_seance }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reservationModal-{{ $seance->id_seance }}" aria-hidden="true">
         ...
    </div>

@endforeach
```

**JS :**

```
$('[id^="reservationModal-"]').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log('works');
});
```

My objective is to find how "replace" `{{ $seance->id_seance }}` by any number in JS to have a generic function.

Thank's for help!

Comment: The selector you're using to find the modal elements is correct and will return you an array of `div.modal` – what is the problem?

Comment: I dont know how to differentiate which modal is open.

Comment: You can access the `div.modal` and therefore the ID of the element inside the `shown.bs.modal` callback where you log 'works' – using the event `e`, you can retrieve the ID using `e.target.id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target of the `shown.bs.modal` event is the `div.modal` from which you can retrieve the element ID – with a bit of parsing, you can get the original value of `id_seance` before it was interpolated.

```js
$('[id^="reservationModal-"]').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    let id_seance = e.target.id.split('-').pop(-1);
    console.log('works', { id_seance });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reservationModal-1">
  Reservation 1
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reservationModal-2">
  Reservation 2
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reservationModal-3">
  Reservation 3
</button>

<div class="modal fade reservationModal" id="reservationModal-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reservationModal-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Reservation 1</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade reservationModal" id="reservationModal-2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reservationModal-2" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Reservation 2</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade reservationModal" id="reservationModal-3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reservationModal-3" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Reservation 3</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `class` to them, like this:

```
$('[id^="reservationModal-"]').addClass("reservationModal");
```

and use this:

```
$(".reservationModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log('works');
});
```

If you want to differentiate the functions, then you can do it like this:

```
$(".reservationModal").each(function() {
    var currentID = this.id;
    $(this).on('shown.bs.modal' function(e) {/*...*/});
});
```

Comment: Why does this work? Does the `on` method require the selector to be a class? o_O